# В значении, в значениях – выбор варианта

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, множественное-число

Пишу технический документ по программированию, нужен правильный вариант заголовка одного из разделов.

Первый вариант:

> Единица и ноль в значени**ях** "Истина" и "Ложь"; они же, в значени**ях** числительных.

Второй вариант:

> Единица и ноль в значени**ях** "Истина" и "Ложь"; они же, в значен**ии** числительных.

Третий вариант:

> Единица и ноль в значен**ии** "Истина" и "Ложь"; они же, в значен**ии** числительных

Какой правильный, почему? Колеблюсь между первым и вторым, хотя, может, и третий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В заголовке лучше придерживаться *строгого* стиля, например: **Единица и ноль в двух значениях истинности** (или "*в аспекте истинности*"; ср. с общепринятым "таблица истинности"). Дело в том, что прямолинейные формулировки "**истина**" и "**ложь**", часто употребляемые в русской терминологии как альтернатива паре "**да/нет**", выглядят в заголовке (т. е. отдельно от последующего контекста) несколько неуклюже (хотя бы из-за оттенка злонамеренности в русском слове "ложь"): они даже не являются прямым переводом слов, с которыми невольно ассоциируются (*true/false* в английском - прилагательные, в сочетании с глаголом "бытия" [is true/false] переводятся как наречия **верно/неверно**).

Comment: Пожалуй, выберу "Единица и ноль в значениях истинности". И так ясно, что их только два. А дополнительное слово "двух" выглядит, на мой взгляд, лишним, да и может запутать: намекнуть, что их существует больше ("в двух значениях истинности из трёх").

Comment: А что с числительными? :-) Там тоже "в значени**ях**"?

Comment: Не думаю, что можно взять и отбросить "двух", не изменив число: в этом случае _значение_ приобретает смысл "аспекта", а не формальной алгебраической величины, - как и в случае "в значении числительных". Пример названия книги: "Погосты в значени**и** правительственных округов".

Comment: Понял, спасибо.